# How to fix weird string result from FPDF?

Tags: php, html, fpdf

Hello i've been trying to get fpdf to work in my webapp so i can output a pdf file that consists of the text from a textarea field and a custom header and footer, i started by trying an example from FPDF website but i get a weird string of characters as output instead of a downloadable pdf file.

this is the form :

```
<form name="f" action="pdf.php" method="get">
   <textarea id="ckeditor" placeholder="Enter text here..." class="form-control" rows="10"></textarea>
   <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

**pdf.php:**

```
<?php
  ob_start();
  require('fpdf/fpdf.php');
  $pdf = new FPDF();
  $pdf->AddPage();
  $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
  $pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World !');
  $pdf->Output();
  ob_end_flush();
?>
```

**result:**

%PDF-1.3 3 0 obj <> endobj 4 0 obj <> stream x�3R��2�35W(�r Q�w3T04�30PISp    �Z*�[����(hx����+���((j*�d�&�w endstream endobj 1 0 obj <> endobj 5 0 obj <> stream x�]R�n�0��>��L�%�DI�8���~�%E*r�ﻻvҪHX�gvVk?/���Ῑ��`]�[�x5 �3\z��P�}����PO���j�Jݍ^���x6/f�����������|���4}�z�����}���@�,ۖ-��˺E�u�^�,���<� �Z_�K� IQ����Yd����C�K�_�%q�8>�!J"V!2&bGģ%r"H��D��}2EL1n��h�j���e��"a*H����:��d��9c���[�X1~��"�3�g��Ñ�;O��> endobj 2 0 obj << /ProcSet [/PDF /Text /ImageB /ImageC /ImageI] /Font << /F1 6 0 R >> /XObject << >> >> endobj 7 0 obj << /Producer (FPDF 1.81) /CreationDate (D:20190226233205) >> endobj 8 0 obj << /Type /Catalog /Pages 1 0 R >> endobj xref 0 9 0000000000 65535 f 0000000229 00000 n 0000000868 00000 n 0000000009 00000 n 0000000087 00000 n 0000000316 00000 n 0000000750 00000 n 0000000972 00000 n 0000001048 00000 n trailer << /Size 9 /Root 8 0 R /Info 7 0 R >> startxref 1097 %%EOF

Comment: Does it work if you remove the `ob_` commands from `pdf.php` or if you simply call `pdf.php` directly?

Comment: Send the appropriate Content-Type along. That's not a "weird string result", but just the raw PDF data when rendered as text/html or /plain.

Comment: PD of [Try to show pdf file using PHP and fpdf](//stackoverflow.com/q/20645034)

Comment: add exit at the end of the file it worked for me.